# Unable to update table via SQL query in Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Not sure if I am making a mistake in using SQL to update a table.

I want to update some data in an existing table but it executes without updating.

Table Field names:

- [Service Aquired on]
- [Next Service due on]
- [Total Amount Received(cr)]

```vb
Dim sao As Date
Dim nso As Date
Dim tap As Currency

sao = Nz(Me.Service_Aquired_on.Value, 0)
nso = Nz(Me.txt_NSDO.Value, 0)
tap = Nz(Me.txt_tatp.Value, 0)

DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Service_MasterData SET([Service Aquired on],[Next Service due on],[Total Amount Received(cr)])" & "VALUES ('" & sao & "', '" & nso & "','" & tap & "')"
```

Kindly assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct SQL syntax for an update statement is :

```
UPDATE Table
SET Column1 =  'Value1'
   ,Column2 = 'Value2'
```

So in your case it would be

```
"UPDATE Service_MasterData SET [Service Aquired on] ='" & sao & "' ,[Next Service due on] ='" & nso & "' ,[Total Amount Received(cr)] ='" & tap & "'"
```

Comment: Thanks this worked but how to use where condition in this scenario since this is updated the entire table for the column kindly assist.

Comment: i am able to use where clause  with your given query ... Thank you lot

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of your [MS Access update query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/update-statement-microsoft-access-sql) is wrong, the general syntax is:

```
update [table]
set [field1] = [value1], [field2] = [value2], ...
```

Hence your query might become:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL _
"UPDATE Service_MasterData " & _
"SET " & _
"    [Service Aquired on] = '" & sao & "', " & _
"    [Next Service due on] = '" & nso & "'," & _
"    [Total Amount Received(cr)] = '" & tap & "'"
```

However, **concatenating user obtained data directly into a SQL statement is strongly discouraged**, as this opens your application to the possibility of [SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/), and will cause your application to break if the user supplies data which includes reserved characters such as single quote string delimiters.

As such, you should consider using parameters, e.g.:

```
With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("","update service_masterdata set [Service Aquired on] = @sao, [Next Service due on] = @nso, [Total Amount Received(cr)] = @tap")
    .Parameters("@sao") = sao
    .Parameters("@nso") = nso
    .Parameters("@tap") = tap
    .Execute
End With
```

Comment: how to use where condition in this scenario since this is updated the entire table for the column kindly assist.

Comment: i would like to use a value of two text value in where condition